# What to look for to clean up site to no longer need compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, web

I have an old site that is using CSS for the site layout.  Unfornuately, some of the pages do not display properly unless you set the brower to compatibility mode.  Then it renders just fine.  I want to fix the pages to display properly without the need of compatibility mode.  I am looking for resources that show what would need to be altered to display properly.  When you click on compatibility mode for the site, what is changing so that the older site renders correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your site web page display properly with compatibility mode.
You use for template for your website whose run any browser and change your old site in new and flexible site. 
  Rather-then you use for browser compatibility different css for different browser.